# Where does the `tf.train.Saver` collect the Variables to save?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I find that if you want to save all the variables of some graph, you must define the `tf.train.Saver` at the last of the graph, otherwise the saver can't get all the variables.

Here are my test code:

```
def how_saver_work():
    g = tf.Graph()

    with g.as_default():

        a = tf.Variable(1, name='a')
        b = tf.Variable(2, name='b')

        print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))
        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        c = tf.Variable(3, name='c')
        print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

            print(a.eval())
            print(b.eval())
            print(c.eval())

            save_path = saver.save(sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")

    with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
        print(g.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))
        saver.restore(sess, save_path)

        print(a.eval())
        print(b.eval())
        print(c.eval())  # err: uninitialized
```

I firstly think that the saver may get the variables from `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` or `tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS`. But it seems wrong.

And I want also know how to add new variables to the Saver. Such as the var `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the `saver` does get its variables from the union of `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` and `tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS` at its construction time (cf. `Saver._build` implementation or the quote below):

```
if self._var_list is None:
    # pylint: disable=protected-access
    self._var_list = variables._all_saveable_objects()
```

where `_all_saveable_objects` is defined in `python/ops/variables.py` file

```
def _all_saveable_objects(scope=None):
  """Returns all variables and `SaveableObject`s that must be checkpointed.

  Args:
    scope: (Optional.) A string. If supplied, the resulting list is filtered
      to include only items whose `name` attribute matches `scope` using
      `re.match`. Items without a `name` attribute are never returned if a
      scope is supplied. The choice of `re.match` means that a `scope` without
      special tokens filters by prefix.

  Returns:
    A list of `Variable` and `SaveableObject` to be checkpointed
  """
  # TODO(andreasst): make this function public once things are settled.
  return (ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope) +
          ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS, scope))
```

There is no way to add variables to a saver apart from creating a new saver (cf https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2489#issuecomment-221282483):

> When you create a `tf.train.Saver` with no arguments, it will implicitly use the current set of variables at the time of Saver construction when it saves and restores. If you add a new variable [...], you have to create a new `tf.train.Saver` to save it.

Comment: Thank you. If so, I want to know that are there some problems if each epoch I create a new saver to save the model?

Comment: I'd say no, but you probably have to pay attention to which saver you use to restore a given checkpoint.